# How do I use the GPU available with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp, gpgpu, offloading

I am trying to get some code to run on the GPU using OpenMP, but I am not succeeding. In my code, I am performing a matrix multiplication using `for` loops: once using OpenMP pragma tags and once without. (This is so that I can compare the execution time.) After the first loop I call `omp_get_num_devices()` (this is my main test to see if I'm actually connecting to a GPU.) No matter what I try, **`omp_get_num_devices()` always returns 0.**

The computer I am using has two **NVIDIA Tesla K40M GPUs**. CUDA 7.0 and CUDA 7.5 are available on the computer as modules, and the CUDA 7.5 module is typically active. gcc 4.9.3, 5.1.0, and 7.1.0 are all available as modules, with gcc 7.1.0 module typically active. I am compiling my code with `$ g++ -fopenmp -omptargets=nvptx64sm_35-nvidia-linux ParallelExperimenting.cpp -o ParallelExperimenting`. I've had OpenMP code successfully parallelized using the CPU, but not with GPUs.

**My main goal here is to get `omp_get_num_devices()` to return 2 as proof that I can detect and use the GPUs with OpenMP.** Any help I recieve here would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am using to check if the GPU is being used correctly or not:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double A [501][501];
double B [501][501];
double C [501][501][501];
double D [501][501];
double E [501][501];
double F [501][501][501];
double dummyvar;
int Mapped [501];

int main() {
    int i, j, k, l, N, StallerGPU, StallerCPU;

    //
    N = 500;

    // Variables merely uses to make the execution take longer and to
    //   exaggurate the difference in performance between first and second
    //   calculation
    StallerGPU = 200;
    StallerCPU = 200;

    std::cout << " N = " << N << "\n";
    // generate matrix to be used in first calculation
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
            if (i == k) {
                A[i][k] = i+1;
            } else {
                A[i][k] = i * k / N;
            }
        }
    }
    // generate other matrix to be used for the first calculation
    for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            B[k][j] = 2*(N-1)-k-j;
        }
    }

//    Slightly adjusted matrices for second calculation
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
            if (i == k) {
                D[i][k] = i+2;
            } else {
                D[i][k] = i * k / N - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            E[k][j] = 2*(N+1)-k-j;
        }
    }

    dummyvar = 0;

    //Run the multiplication in parallel using GPUs

    double diff;
    time_t time1;
    time1 = time( NULL ); // CPU time counter
    cout << endl << " GPU section begins at " << ctime(&time1) << endl;

        //    This pragma is frequently changed to try different tags
        #pragma omp for collapse(4) private(i, j, k, l)

        for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
//            Mapped[i] = omp_is_initial_device();
            for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
                for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
                    for(l = 0; l < StallerGPU; l++ ) {
                        C[i][j][k] = A[i][k] * B[k][j] ;
                        dummyvar += A[i][k] * B[k][j] * (l + 1);
                    }
                }
//            cout << " i " << i << endl;
            }
        }


    //record the time it took to run the multiplication    
    time_t time2 = time( NULL );
    cout << " number of devices: " << omp_get_num_devices() << endl;
    cout << " dummy variable: " << dummyvar << endl;

    float cpumin = difftime(time2,time1);
    diff = difftime(time2,time1);
    cout << " stopping at delta GPU time: " << cpumin << endl; 
    cout << " terminating at " << ctime(&time2) << endl;
    cout << " GPU time elasped " << diff << " s" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    dummyvar = 0;
    time_t time3 = time( NULL );
    cout << endl << " CPU section begins at " << ctime(&time3) << endl;
//    #pragma omp single
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
                for (int l=0; l<StallerCPU; l++) {
                    F[i][j][k] = D[i][k] * E[k][j];
                    dummyvar += D[i][k] * E[k][j] * (l - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // the sum to complete the matrix calculation is left out here, but would
    // only be used to check if the result of the calculation is correct

    time_t time4 = time( NULL );
    cpumin = difftime(time4,time3);
    diff = difftime(time4,time3);
    cout << " dummy variable: " << dummyvar << endl;
    cout << " stopping at delta CPU time: " << cpumin << endl; 
    cout << " terminating at " << ctime(&time4) << endl;
    cout << " CPU time elasped " << diff << " s" << endl;
    //Compare the time it took to confirm that we actually used GPUs to parallelize.
}
```

Here is the result of running the deviceQuery sample CUDA code.

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 2 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Tesla K40m"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5
  Total amount of global memory:                 11520 MBytes (12079136768 bytes)
  (15) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     2880 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            745 MHz (0.75 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             3004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1572864 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Enabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 130 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

Device 1: "Tesla K40m"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5
  Total amount of global memory:                 11520 MBytes (12079136768 bytes)
  (15) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     2880 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            745 MHz (0.75 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             3004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1572864 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Enabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 131 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
> Peer access from Tesla K40m (GPU0) -> Tesla K40m (GPU1) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla K40m (GPU1) -> Tesla K40m (GPU0) : Yes

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.5, NumDevs = 2, Device0 = Tesla K40m, Device1 = Tesla K40m
Result = PASS
```

Comment: Can you upload a minimum working example showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post is unfortunately missing a [mcve]. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added my testing code.

Comment: Where did you get the `-omptargets=` from? It's a clang's option, not gcc's.

Comment: I have tried using clang as well to get this working, so that's probably where I came up with the `-omptargets=`. I can remove it, but removing it does not change my ability to connect to the GPU.

Comment: @Shadow The goal of this code is not performance or functionality, but to prove that I am using the GPUs. I've come across the presentation you linked in your comment before, so I have been using `omp_get_num_devices()` as my primary test to see that I can detect the GPUs. Aside from that, I am intentionally killing performance to attempt to exaggerate the difference between the (supposedly) offloaded calculation and the other one. The only purpose of dummyvar is to ensure that the code isn't optimized away by the compiler. I don't even care what the output is.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what your problem is. I was thinking in the wrong direction. So you are mainly complaining about that `omp_get_num_devices()` never returns `1`? Then why don't make your code really minimal with just that simple call? If that's working you should be able to do the rest on your own.

Comment: Hopefully the statement I changed made it more clear now.

Comment: I guess your GCC doesn't support offloading to GPU. Actually this feature requires 2 different GCCs installed (gcc targeting host and gcc targeting gpu). I'm not sure whether there are such packages in your distro, I'd prefer to build both from sources as described [here](https://gist.github.com/kristerw/4e9a735f2d755ffa73f9bf27edbf3c29).

Comment: That should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 4.9.3 and 5.1.0 definitely do not support OpenMP offloading to GPU.
GCC 7.1.0 does support it, however it should be built with special configure options, [as described here](https://kristerw.blogspot.ru/2017/04/building-gcc-with-support-for-nvidia.html).

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong, but I think you need a few corrections to the code as posted (maybe you already know it).  To actually run on the GPU target with OpenMP you need to replace:

```
#pragma omp for collapse(4) private(i, j, k, l)
```

with

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for collapse(4) private(i, j, k, l)
```

You can verify if the kernel is actually running on the GPU by profiling your executable with 'nvprof'.  It should show a kernel executing on the GPU.  You can also change the number of teams and threads in your target region using the 'num_teams' and 'thread_limit' clauses and you should see corresponding changes in your profile.

To actually check programmatically if a target region is running on a target device I use the 'omp_is_initial_device()' call, which returns 0 when called from the accelerator.  Here's an example:

```
int A[1] = {-1};
#pragma omp target
{
  A[0] = omp_is_initial_device();
}

if (!A[0]) {
  printf("Able to use offloading!\n");
}
```

Comment: I tried to profile it with `nvprof` as you suggested. After the program completes its execution, I receive an error `======== Warning: No CUDA application was profiled, exiting`. When I add in `omp_is_initial_device()`, it returns a 1 each time.

Comment: This seems to strongly suggest that your kernel is running on the CPU.  As  Ilya mentioned, you probably need to compile gcc with gpu support.

Comment: Why do you need to use an array of one element rather than just a simple integer? I tried your code and it only works with an array but I don't understand why.

Comment: I figured it out. Scalar values default to `firstprivate`. So the pointer is effectively shared. `#pragma omp target defaultmap(tofrom:scalar)` lets scalars be shared.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm in a wrong direction. but I want to help,

since I've ever in a weird situation using GPU.

You need to be in the "video" group of linux, so you can using GPU.

or all the results returned from GPU will be 0.

So I would advise you run a sample CUDA code to check if you are in the situation I used to be stuck.

It's weird. I'm not sure I describe it properly. 
hope it helps.

---

according to this: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVidia/nvidia-drivers

> The user(s) needing to access the video card will need to be added to
>   the video group

Comment: Why don't you provide a link reference? It sounds a good answer and with that it'll sounds even better

Comment: I will add the results of running the deviceQuery sample CUDA code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Thx. I didn't know AMD GPU also need this.